# ValueError: too many values to unpack 4

Tags: python

```
for n, row in spamreader:
    print('row')
    print('debug point 4')
    cur.execute('''INSERT INTO table(col1,col2,col3,col4)values (%s,%s,%s,%s)''',row)
    if n % 2 == 0:
        connect.commit()
 connect.commit()
```

The file that I am reading from has exactly 4 columns. Still I am getting the below error

```
File "test_new.py", line 22, in <module>
    for n, row in spamreader:
ValueError: too many values to unpack
```

Comment: How is `spamreader` defined?
I geuss you look for `for n, row in enumerate(spamreader):`

Comment: you are expecting two values(n, row) for each iteration(tuple of length 2) but there are more values than that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that when you iterate over `spamreader` you expect two variables - 
`n` - which according to the rest of the code is probably the line number
`row` - the row itself.

What you actually need to do in order to get the row number is -

```
for n, row in enumerate(spamreader):
```

Assuming `spamreader` reads the rows as expected (definition of `spamreader` is not given currently) this should do the job.

See more about using enumerate [here](http://book.pythontips.com/en/latest/enumerate.html).

Comment: Thanks . It works. But the insert statement goes on forever and never ends..Any clues?

Answer (score 2):

try

```
 for n, row in spamreader.iterrows():
```

for pandas dataframe you have to use `df.iterrows():`

`n` will be your index. in `row`
 you can access your data like `row['column_name']`